# Optimal query to fetch same-rows multiple times

Tags: mysql

The legend says:

> We have a table of Events with 3
>   fields: id (INT), date_start (DATE),
>   date_end (DATE), and in this table we
>   have numerous of rows which can have
>   same ranges in date_start-date_end or
>   different.

For example: we can have an event that lasts from 2011-06-01 to 2011-06-08 and of course we can have an event that lasts from 2011-06-01 to 2011-06-01.

The question is:

> **What are the most optimal queries to:**

1. Fetch events for a month day by day to get such thing:

   - 2011-06-01
   - ID: 1
   - ID: 2
   - ID: 3
   - ID: 4
   - ID: 5
   - ...
   - 2011-06-02
   - ID: 1
   - ID: 3
   - ID: 4
   - ...
   - 2011-06-02
   - ID: 3
   - ID: 6
   - ...
   - and so on.
2. Fetch all possible months and number of events for those months to get such thing:

   - 2011-06, 00
   - 2011-07, 05
   - 2011-08, 25
   - 2011-09, 15
   - 2011-10, 23
   - 2011-11, 00
   - 2011-12, 11
   - 2012-01, 00
   - and so on.

Comment: There are plenty of gaps-and-islands and date-related duplicates of your question. It also helps to try before asking.

Comment: Creative use of `BETWEEN` should do what you want. Try some things out and then ask if you have more specific things you can't work out how to do.